# fetch details from other documents

Tags: join, mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-1.6

Let's say I design a couchdb app for taking orders in a bar.
I have a database containing products and orders.

A product looks like:

```
{ _id: "beer", type: "product", price: 5 }
{ _id: "juice", type: "product", price: 2 }
```

And an order looks like:

```
{ _id: "order for table 1", type: "order", items: { "beer": 1, "juice": 4 } }
```

Here, the *table 1* has ordered *1 beer* and *4 juices*.

I want to create a design document that would output something like

```
{
  _id: "order for table 1",
  items: {
    beer: {
      price: 5,
      quantity: 1
    },
    juice: {
      price: 2,
      quantity: 4
    }
  }
}
```

What does the map function looks like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved via map-side join, if your `product` JSON is small dataset. A possible logic:

```
1) Use the product file as static input to the mapper. Use `DistributedCahe` or alternatively you may add a big `JSON` object consisting of all the products into the context.

2) In the Mapper, make sure that one order is input to the mapper. Using `product` file from `DistributedCahe` (or `product` JSON from the context); create your output JSON and write to context.

3) You do not need a reducer here.
```